# Two possible realisations for amplifier network - which is better, when and why?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

Suppose the following transfer function should be realised using idealised components,

\$H(s)=-\frac{s+12}{s+8}\$.

I now define the following functions to act as "building blocks" for a network:

\$\textrm{INV}(Z_1, Z_f) \$ constructs an inverting amplifier configuration with given impedences, where \$Z_f\$ is the impedance in the feedback path.

\$\textrm{INV}_{A_V=n} \$ constructs an inverting amplifier with given voltage gain, \$n\$.

An equivalent \$\overline{\textrm{INV}} \$ is used to construct non-inverting amplifier networks in a similar fashion.

It is clear that \$H(s)\$ can be realised by \$\textrm{INV}(s+8, s+12)\$.

By writing \$H(s) =-1(1+\frac{4}{s+8})\$, this shows that it can also be realised as \$\overline{\textrm{INV}}(s+8, 4)\textrm{INV}_{A_V=-1}\$.

I would presume that the first method would be preferred, due to less energy dissipation (only one amplifier). However, are there any real applications in which the second method would likely yield better results when physical components are taken into account?

Comment: There's a schematic editor here when you edit your question. Please use it.

Comment: @Hearth I'm aware. I have carefully written this question such that an intuition can quickly be gained without bulky schematics.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I find schematics *way* easier to intuit than this.